# Is Cargo a dependency to build Cargo itself from source?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The [Cargo README](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo) states the following:

> ### Compiling from Source
>
> Cargo requires the following tools and packages to build:
>
> - `python`
> - `curl` (on Unix)
> - `cmake`
> - OpenSSL headers (only for Unix, this is the `libssl-dev` package on ubuntu)
> - `cargo` and `rustc`
>
> First, you'll want to check out this repository
>
> ```
> git clone --recursive https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo 
> cd cargo
> ```
>
> With `cargo` already installed, you can simply run:
>
> ```
> cargo build --release
> ```
>
> Otherwise, you can also use a more traditional approach:
>
> ```
> ./configure
> make
> make install
> ```

It indicates that Cargo is a dependency for building Cargo, but also seems to indicate that if Cargo is not installed then the method starting with `./configure` should work.

When I clone that repo and run `./configure` I get an error

```
...
configure: found cmake
configure: found make
configure: recreating config.tmp
configure: 
configure: processing ./configure args
configure: 
configure: CFG_PREFIX           := /usr/local 
configure: CFG_LOCAL_RUST_ROOT  :=  
configure: CFG_CARGO            := cargo 
configure: CFG_RUSTC            := rustc 
configure: CFG_RUSTDOC          := rustdoc 
configure: CFG_CARGO            :=  
configure: error: needed, but unable to find any of: CFG_CARGO cargo
```

Does this mean I can't build Cargo from source without having Cargo installed? Maybe an argument to `configure` is missing?

I built Rust from source because I am not a privileged user on this system and have the installation in my user directory.

Comment: You don't need to build Rust or Cargo yourself just because you are not a privileged user. [Rustup](https://rustup.rs/) installs everything to your home directory.

Comment: Well I'll be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the discussion here [Issue 3772](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3772):

> Indeed yeah Cargo is required to compile Cargo. In future Rust releases we'll have --enable-extended which will compile Cargo as well as Rust.

But some cargo bootstrapping scripts could be found. For example: https://github.com/dhuseby/cargo-bootstrap.